# How do you find the probability of P(a and b)?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

The probability model has a sample space of {A,B,C} with P(A) = 0.1, P(B) = 0.8, P(C) = 0.1. I found that P(B or C) = 0.9 because the probabilities add, but I cannot figure out P(A and B).

Comment: Are you familiar with disjoint events?

Answer (score 1):

Think about what this means:

$P(A \text{ or } B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \text{ and } B)$

I suggest drawing a Venn Diagram to see what the quantities in this formula represent. You'll find that one of the quantities must be zero.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the events are disjoint $P(A \cap B)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what this means:

P(B or C)=P(B)+P(C)−P(B and C)
P(B)=0.8
P(C)=0.1
P(B or C)=0.9
so, we got P(B and C)=0
i.e.P(B ∩ C)=0
that denotes both B and C are disjoint events.

Similarly,
P(A or B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A and B)
P(A) = 0.1, P(B) = 0.8
P(A and B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A or B)
P(A and B)=0.9-P(A or B)
P(A and B) will be minimum when both are disjoint, i.e. 0
P(A and B) will be maximum when one is subset of other i.e. 0.1
0<=P(A ∩ B)<=0.1